# Python Popen failing to use proper encoding in Windows PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, unicode, mercurial

I am running my Python script in Windows PowerShell, and the script should run another program using Popen, then pipe the output of that program (Mercurial, actually) for use in my script. I am getting an encoding error when I try to execute my script in PowerShell.

I am quite sure it is happening because Python is not using the correct encoding that PowerShell is using, when getting the output of the Popen call. **The problem is that I don't know how to tell Python to use the correct encoding.**

---

My script looks like

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#... some imports
proc = Popen(["hg", "--cwd", self.path, "--encoding", "UTF-8"] + list(args), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
#... other code
```

When I run this script on Linux, I have no problems whatsoever. I can also run the script in Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit using PowerShell with no problems. The PowerShell in this Windows 7 is using the code page 850, that is, the output of `chcp` is `850` ("ibm850").

**However**, when I run the script in a **Windows 7 Starter 32-bits** using a PowerShell that has by default the encoding cp437 (`chcp` = `437`), I get the following error from Python (version 2.7.2):

```
File "D:\Path\to\myscript.py", line 55, in hg_command
    proc = Popen(["hg", "--cwd", self.path, "--encoding", "UTF-8"] + list(args), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
File "C:\Program files\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
File "C:\Program files\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 852, in _execute_child
    args = list2cmdline(args)
File "C:\Program files\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 615, in list2cmdline
    return ''.join(result)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec cant decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: unexpected end of data
```

I have tried the following, with no success (i.e., the above error report stays the same):

- Remove the line `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` from my script.
- Remove the `-- encoding UTF-8` option for running Mercurial through Popen in my script.
- Change the encoding to `chcp 850` in PowerShell before executing my script.
- Many other miscellaneous Python hacks I've found in other Stack Overflow answers.

For my specific details, my whole source code is available [here in BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/staltz/hypergrass/src/2d7730269e04/src/). `hgapi.py` is the script that gives the error.

---

**UPDATE:**
The script is being called by this [other script](https://bitbucket.org/staltz/hypergrass/src/2d7730269e04/src/win_runscripts/hypergrass.py), which is setting the encoding like this

```
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")
```

This line looks important, because if I comment it out, I get a different error:

```
UnicodeDecoreError: 'ascii' codec cant decode byte 0xe3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Do you have the same problem when using the [mercurial api](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MercurialApi)? Since you are using python it seems like a natural fit.

Comment: The project used to use the mercurial internal api, but I switched to the command line api because that's the official stable one. The internal api is not supposed to be used except for extensions.

Comment: This looks more like a problem with the `args` array since the exception is raised in `list2cmdline`. Maybe `args` or `self.path` is a byte string instead of a Unicode string?

Comment: On Windows, you generally want to use Unicode strings wherever possible. `hgapi.py` turns all string literals into Unicode literals (`from __future__ import unicode_literals`), and `hypergrasscore.py` should probably do the same.

Comment: @Philipp, that makes sense. However, I have added `from __future__ import unicode_literals` and I still get the same error. In fact, I even included `u` before strings (`u'string'`) in my hypergrasscore.py script that calls hgapi.py, but no success. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After using `from __future__ import unicode_literals` I started getting the same error but in a different part of the code:

```
out, err = [x.decode("utf-8") for x in  proc.communicate()]
```

Gave the error

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec cant decode byte 0xe3 in position 33 ....
```

Indeed, `x` was a **byte string** with `\xe3` (which is `ã` in cp1252) included. So instead of using `x.decode('utf-8')`, I used `x.decode('windows-1252')` and that gave me no bugs. To support any kind of encoding, I ended up using `x.decode(sys.stdout.encoding)` instead. **Problem solved.**

And that was in Python 3.2.2 with the Windows 7 Starter computer, but Python 2.7 on the same computer also worked normally.

Comment: Interesting - in my case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28101187/deal-with-unicode-usernames-in-python-mkdtemp `sys.stdout.encoding` is None - would locale.getpreferredencoding() do the trick ?

Answer (score 3):

Try to change the encoding to `cp1252`. Popen in Windows wants shell commands encoded as `cp1252`. This seems like a bug, and it also seems fixed in Python 3.X through the `subprocess` module: http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["hg", "--cwd", self.path, "--encoding", "UTF-8"] + list(args), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

**update:**

Your problem maybe can be solved through **smart_str** function of Django module.

Use this code:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str, smart_unicode
# the cmd should contain sthe string with the commsnd that you want to execute
smart_cmd = smart_str(cmd)
subprocess.Popen(smart_cmd)
```

You can find information on how to install Django on Windows [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/?from=olddocs#install-the-django-code).
You can first install [pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-to-install-pip-on-windows) and then you can install Django by starting
a command shell with administrator privileges and run this command:

```
pip install Django
```

This will install Django in your Python installation's site-packages directory.

Comment: Change the encoding to cp1252 through what? `chcp 1252` in PowerShell doesn't help.

Comment: @STALTZ Try `$OutputEncoding = [Console]::OutputEncoding`

Comment: @STALTZ I am sorry maybe my updated answer can help you but you have to install a new module, the django. `smart_str` is a very helpful function. You can find more information here: http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2008/11/python-unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character/

Comment: I haven't tried yet your Django solution, @ThanasisPetsas, because I think there should be some basic Python solution for this. Thanks anyway, if I don't find another solution I can eventually use Django.