# Deal with unicode usernames in python mkdtemp

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I was bitten by http://bugs.python.org/issue1681974 - quoting from there:

> mkdtemp fails on Windows if Windows user name has any non-ASCII characters, like ä or ö, in it. mkdtemp throws an encoding error. This seems to be because the default temp dir in Windows is `"c:\documents and settings\<user name>\local settings\temp"`

The workaround the OP used is:

```
try: # workaround for http://bugs.python.org/issue1681974
    return tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix)
except UnicodeDecodeError:
    tempdir = unicode(tempfile.gettempdir(), 'mbcs')
    return tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix, dir=tempdir)
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why this should work ?
2. How full proof is this ? From a similar questions (see this answer: [Python Popen failing to use proper encoding in Windows PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9992381/python-popen-failing-to-use-proper-encoding-in-windows-powershell/10114320#10114320)) I got the notion that I maybe should use `sys.stdout.encoding` - am I anywhere near the mark ?

**Edit:** actually the line:

```
print u"input encoding: %s; output encoding: %s; locale: %s" % (
    sys.stdin.encoding,getattr(sys.stdout,'encoding',None),
    locale.getdefaultlocale())
```

prints

> input encoding: None; output encoding: None; locale: ('ja_JP', 'cp932')

so maybe I should go for locale.getpreferredencoding() (see for instance [subprocess.Popen with a unicode path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941064/subprocess-popen-with-a-unicode-path/9951851#9951851))

**Edit2:** in the comments it is suggested I encode the prefix in mbcs - unfortunately this is not an option as the codebase expects unicode everywhere and will blow sooner or later. The code posted is a simplified fragment.

**Edit3**: my little workaround apparently did not workaround anything - will try:

```
fsenc = sys.getfilesystemencoding() or 'mbcs'
return tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix.encode(fsenc)).decode(fsenc)
```

if there's any non ascii user left to test that is.

Meanwhile - the reproducers below don't work for me:

```
C:\_\Python27\python.exe -u C:\__\JetBrains\PyCharm 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevconsole.py 18324 18325
PyDev console: starting.import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
sys.path.extend(['C:\\Dropbox\\eclipse_workspaces\\python\\wrye-bash'])
>>> d = u'ελληνικα'.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()); os.environ['TEMP'] = os.path.abspath(d)
>>> import tempfile; tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=u'x')
u'c:\\users\\mrd\\appdata\\local\\temp\\xtf3nav'
```

and variations...

edit4 - the directory exists in an absolute sense:

```
>>> d = u'ελληνικα'.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()); os.path.abspath(d)
'C:\\Dropbox\\eclipse_workspaces\\python\\wrye-bash\\e??????a'
>>> assert os.path.isdir(os.path.abspath(d))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
AssertionError
>>> d = u'ελληνικα'
>>> os.path.abspath(d)
u'C:\\Dropbox\\eclipse_workspaces\\python\\wrye-bash\\\u03b5\u03bb\u03bb\u03b7\u03bd\u03b9\u03ba\u03b1'
>>> assert os.path.isdir(os.path.abspath(d))
>>>
```

Comment: @eryksun: they discuss this in the bug - the problem is the username - how full proof would mbsc be - would it work for the japanese user alright ?

Comment: No, it's not merely the username, because `os.path.join` won't raise a `UnicodeDecodeError` unless you're mixing a non-ASCII `str` with `unicode`. That happens in this case if `prefix` is `unicode`.

Comment: `'mbcs'` is implemented using Windows `MultiByteToWideChar` (decode) and `WideCharToMultiByte` (encode) for the `CP_ACP` encoding (the system ANSI encoding), which is what `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns. That said, Python's codec for `'cp932'` is probably more strict than Windows when it comes to undefined characters. I know that's the case for `'cp1252'`, which fails for `'\x81'.decode('cp1252')`, while `'\x81'.decode('mbcs') == u'\x81'`.

Comment: the issue is marked "out of date". If you see the failure on Python 2.7; please, leave the message on the bug tracker.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, to replicate the `UnicodeDecodeError`, set `os.environ['TEMP']` to an existing path that contains a non-ASCII character and then pass a `unicode` string for `prefix`.

Comment: @eryksun: thanks for the reproducer. I edited the question to clarify that using a str prefix is not an option.

Comment: have you tried `return tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix.encode('mbcs') if isinstance(prefix, unicode) else prefix).decode('mbcs')`? (for portability, you could use `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` here). On Python 3, just pass the unicode string as is.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: the code posted is simplified - I need the return value to be in unicode. So I would need to reencode that ? Would `tempdir = unicode(tempfile.gettempdir(), sys.getfilesystemencoding())
    return tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix, dir=tempdir)` be the answer (without messing with the prefix) ?

Comment: the code in my comment returns `unicode`. It is all the code there is: no try/except.

Comment: @eryksun: I can reproduce it even on Linux in Python 2: `import os, sys; os.environ['TEMP'] = d = u'\N{SNOWMAN}'.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding()); assert os.path.isdir(d)`. Then `import tempfile; tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=u'x')` raises `UnicodeDecodeError` on `path += '/' + b` line in `posixpath.py`. It is the same error as: `path = u'\N{SNOWMAN}'.encode('utf-8'); path += '/' + u'x'`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: right - the prefix will always be unicode in my case - would then `return tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())).decode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())` be the answer ? - if yes post it please

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: unless `isinstance()` call is a performance bottleneck in your application (I doubt it); leave it. In principle, `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` may be `None` in some cases before Python 3.2 (it is `None` in Jython) -- test it. If you tested and the solution works for you; you can [post it as your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I was (kindly) requested to fill a bug report in (http://bugs.python.org/issue1681974) - I really do not qualify to make it - I would accept as an answer a link to a bug report. The prefix is under my control - so that'd be `fsenc = sys.getfilesystemencoding() or 'mbcs'; return tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix.encode(fsenc)).decode(fsenc)` ? I do post answers to my questions it's just that testing is not trivial in my setup

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D: `assert os.path.isdir(d)` is not optional. If `d` is not a directory; `tempfile` won't use it.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: see edit4

Comment: No. The directory does not exist. The system considers the paths to be *different* in this case. Call `os.mkdir(d)` to make sure it exists

Comment: You mean: `>>> os.environ['TEMP'] = d = u'ελληνικα'.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())
>>> os.mkdir(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'e??????a'` - I had tried this of course (it's in the "variations" clause)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: And my favorite variation: `>>> import os, sys; os.environ['TEMP'] = d = u'ελληνικα'; os.path.abspath(d)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\_\Python27\lib\os.py", line 422, in __setitem__
    putenv(key, item)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-7: ordinal not in range(128)`. As far as I am concerned all these tracebacks are bugs. Anyway let's hear from the user - if ever again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally went with:

```
sys_fs_enc = sys.getfilesystemencoding() or 'mbcs'

@staticmethod
def tempDir(prefix=None):
    try: # workaround for http://bugs.python.org/issue1681974 see there
        return tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix)
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        try:
            traceback.print_exc()
            print 'Trying to pass temp dir in...'
            tempdir = unicode(tempfile.gettempdir(), sys_fs_enc)
            return tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix=prefix, dir=tempdir)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            try:
                traceback.print_exc()
                print 'Trying to encode temp dir prefix...'
                return tempfile.mkdtemp(
                    prefix=prefix.encode(sys_fs_enc)).decode(sys_fs_enc)
            except:
                traceback.print_exc()
                print 'Failed to create tmp dir, Bash will not function ' \
                      'correctly.'
```

[Apparently](http://pastebin.com/3Ek4mMvN) the first try catch is sufficient but I left the tracebacks in so I can get some more input ;)