# Largest number of rows in a csv python can handle?

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
with open("C:\Anaconda3\FalkParameters\AllModels.csv","r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    listofModels = list(reader)
```

AllModels is a huge csv file (2.4 GB). I am not sure how many rows are in there, because I can't open it with any application (notepad, notepad++, excel, etc.).

The code above runs okay, but if I try to print "listofModels", the console starts printing, but at some point I get a "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file". Printing stops at different rows each time.

I was wondering if there is a way I can deal with huge csv files in python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't convert it to list. Rather use generator instead.
print one value/line at a time.

```
for line in reader:
    print line
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: I'm sure it does!

Comment: Yes, because printing huge file at a time will be the reason for memory full so wont be able to print it.

Comment: Great. Thanks much!